# Can I use an external monitor with my late 2009 21.5 inch iMac?

Tags: imac

Basically, I'm wondering with the proper cables if can hook up an additional monitor to my late 2009 21.5" iMac. I know the 27" iMacs are able to be hooked up to external monitors, I'm just worried I won't be able to in the 21.5". Does anyone know if this will be possible?

Answer (score 2):

The [support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3913) shows that you can connect it to an external monitor.

> Apple Mini DisplayPort video port
>
> Using the Mini DisplayPort video output port, mirror video or extend the size of your Mac OS X desktop (extended desktop mode) with a compatible DVI (Digital Visual Interface) display or VGA (Video Graphics Display) or projector using the appropriate Mini DisplayPort adapter:

Answer (score 0):

Actually the next paragraph limits that to just 27's.:

Apple Mini DisplayPort video port

Using the Mini DisplayPort video output port, mirror video or extend the size of your Mac OS X desktop (extended desktop mode) with a compatible DVI (Digital Visual Interface) display or VGA (Video Graphics Display) or projector using the appropriate Mini DisplayPort adapter:

```
For Single Link DVI displays, use the Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter (MB570Z/A).
For Dual-Link DVI displays, use the Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter (MB571Z/A).
For VGA displays or projectors use the Mini DisplayPort to VGA Display Adapter (MB572Z/A).
```

Video mirroring

With video mirroring, you can see the image that is on the iMac flat-panel display on an external monitor, television, or projector.

Extended desktop mode

Connect an external display and use that area in addition to the built-in display for your desktop.

Audio output

The iMac (Mid 2010) supplies an audio signal from the Mini DisplayPort.  For this feature, use Mini-DisplayPort to HDMI adapters that conform to the VESA v1.1a DisplayPort Interoperability Guidelines.

The Mini DisplayPort video port on the 27-inch iMac also supports video input from DisplayPort compliant sources.

Target Display Mode

**Use the 27-inch iMac display as an external display for another computer, like a MacBook Pro.** Return to the iMac screen by pressing Command + F2 on the keyboard. Note: Requires Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable or a converter that converts other electrical, video and audio protocols to DisplayPort compliant signals.  Read more about using this feature in Using a 27-inch iMac as an external display.